# Java 8 Streams. Collectors.groupingBy on many fields?

Tags: java, c#, java-stream

Can someone help to translate this C# code of grouping collection of objects by three properties and projection into collection of Positions into Java Streams, please?

```
.GroupBy(am => new {am.Date, am.ProductId, am.Code})
.Select(res => new Position
                                       {
                                           ExpiryDate = res.Key.Date,
                                           TotalQuantity = res.Sum(pm => pm.Quantity),
                                           Code = res.Key.Code 
                                       });
```

Comment: Could you show an example of input/output? I'm not very familiar with C#. I guess a composition of `groupingBy`/`mapping` should do it.

Comment: What does your current java code look like?  Not sure what you are going for.  Nested maps or group by some triplet.